Solving a "One Away.." connections group with nine guesses

Being somewhat mediocre, I opened a connections game entitled "So Easy!!!" and enabled infinite guesses. However,  I couldn't see even the slighest connection between the words! (Can you tell this is based off real events?)  Frustrated, I tried the first four words and, while this wasn't a category, it was "One away...".  Show there is a method to find that connection within at most nine more guesses, even in the worst case.
Clarifications:

While the goal is normally to find four groups of four words, the goal here is just to find the one group of four words that I almost got with my first guess.
While the nine more guesses does not include the initial "One away...", it does include the final guess where you are correct.
The app always tells you if you are "One away..." i.e. your guess has three of the four words.  It also tells you if you are correct of course, but provides no other hints.
This is meant to be a optimization problem, so assume the words are of no help, and any four words are equally likely to be the intended category.
I'm pretty sure nine is the best you can do but I don't have a formal proof.


I can see why you were frustrated by that board. ‘So Easy’ indeed – or utterly, utterly impossible, unless you happen to magically realise that you need to discount all the initial letters. ‍♂️

First, partition the last twelve words into

four singles and four pairs.

Next, make four guesses using

three of the initial words and one of the singles, where each guess substitutes a different initial word for a different single.

There are three cases:

One of the singles is correct, and we substitute it for the incorrect initial word. This yields zero one-away groups.
One of the singles is correct, and we substitute it for a correct initial word. This yields two one-away groups.
None of the singles is correct. This yields one one-away group.

Because each case

yields a different number of one-away groups, we can use this total to determine which case we are in.

In the first case,

one of the guesses is correct, and we win immediately, having made at most four guesses.

In the second case,

there are only two possibilities for the connection, so we can win with two more guesses, for a total of six guesses.

In the third case,

we learn the three correct initial words. Then we can make three guesses using two correct initial words and a unique remaining pair of words to determine the pair that has the correct fourth word. Based on this pair, we can win with two more guesses, for a total of nine guesses.

In each case, we find the correct connection within at most nine more guesses.

More elegant than my solution, nice!


 The answer occurs in two phases.  First, let the four words in the initial "one away" set be $A, B, C, D$.  Select an additional word $E$ at random.  Then test the sets $A, B, C, E$ and $A, B, D, E$ (of course, this is just one instance of a general form).    We have used two guesses.  This is what we learn:


If (uncommonly) both sets are one away, then $A$ or $B$ is not in the answer set (as $E$ must be within it, and if either $C$ or $D$ were not then we would have already solved).  If this is the case, the answer is one of $A, C, D, E$ or $B, C, D, E$ for four guesses total.  If this is not the case, we know $E$ to not be in the answer set, having used two guesses, and may also determine:


If one set is one away and the other is not, then $A, B$ are in the answer set, as well as the one of $C, D$ that was present for the one-away judgement (as we know that $E$ is not in the answer set).  We now know three of the four words with certainty (either $A, B, C$ or $A, B, D$).


If both sets are not one away, then either $A$ or $B$ are not in the answer set, and we know that $C, D$ is within.


Establishing that, we select two of the words we know to be in the answer set from above.  Then, we test those two words with pairs of the remaining words.  When we are one away, the new pair contains the final word.  There are six pairs, requiring five tests (failing the first five implying, of course, that the sixth is positive).  In the worst case, we use 5 guesses here for a total of 7.


In the cases above where we know three words of the answer set, we can test them with first one, then the other in the pair, and one of them will be correct, for a worst-case additional 2 guesses, total 9.


In the case where we do not know if $A$ or $B$ is the excluded word, then we knew that $E$ was also not the relevant word.  If we save the pair containing $E$ for last, then we know the other word to be the fourth word, and instead use the two guesses to replace $A$ and $B$ with the last word, one of which will be correct, for a worst-case additional 2 guesses, also total 9.


I think you're 97% of the way there, but I'm a bit concerned about one case: ABCE (not one away), ABDE (not one away)
CDFG, CDHI, CDJK, CDLM, CDNO (one away).  You've used 7 guesses but you don't know A or B, and you don't know N or O.

Ah, you're right, there's a special case there that I should have specified above; apologies.  The second guess should be BCDE if ABCE was not one away; if it is also not one away, then it is A and not B, and continue as above.  If it is one away, it is B and not A, and continue as above.  Then once at the CDNO case you present, it is known which of A/B are in, meaning you only need two guesses to determine N vs O.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but if ABCE is not one away, and BCDE is not one away, now you know A and D are in but you don't know which one of B and C are in, and you're in the same boat, right?

My reasoning is:  if ABCD is in (given), one (and only one) of the triplets ABC, ABD, or BCD are three correct words.  If ABCE is out, it cannot be ABC.  If then BCDE is also out, it cannot be BCD; therefore the only remaining option is ABD.  Similar reductions follow in the other cases.

If ABCD is one away, then there should be four options:  ABC, ABD, ACD, and BCD.

...that's completely correct, and I think I've been too long without eating, or something.  Sorry, my mistake.  I'll have to reformulate a little.

Let's (attempt to) prove that eight guesses are insufficient in the worst case.
Summary
We can associate each possible correct connection with a pair of an incorrect initial word and a correct non-initial word. Considering the possible words in these pairs, the best guesses either

use two initial words and two non-initial words, eliminating the two non-initial words, or
use three initial words and one non-initial word, eliminating the unused initial word and the non-initial word.

Either way, after six guesses, at least $16-2\times6=4$ total words are left, which requires at least three more guesses.
Sketch
Let $A$ be the set of four words in the initial guess.
Let $B$ be the set of twelve other words.
Let $C$ be the set of four words in the correct connection.
Let $x=A\setminus C$ and $y=B\cap C$. Finding $C$ is equivalent to finding the pair $(x,y)\in A\times B$.
Let $A_0=A$ and $B_0=B$. After the initial guess, all pairs in $A_0\times B_0$ are possible.
Assume $r\ge0$ more guesses have been made and $A_r\subseteq A$ and $B_r\subseteq B$ are defined such that all pairs in $A_r\times B_r$ are possible.
Let $G$ be the set of four words in the subsequent guess.
If $G\cap C\le2$, the guess is wrong. If $G\cap C$ is $3$ or $4$, the guess is one-off or correct, respectively.
Our goal is to categorize the guess and choose $A_{r+1}\subseteq A_r$ and $B_{r+1}\subseteq B_r$ such that all pairs in $A_{r+1}\times B_{r+1}$ are possible.
Let's case on $|G\cap A|$ and consider $\Delta=|A_r|-|A_{r+1}|+|B_r|-|B_{r+1}|$.

$|G\cap A|\le1$: The guess is wrong, so we can choose $A_{r+1}=A_r$ and $B_{r+1}=B_r$ where $\Delta=0$.
$|G\cap A|=2$:

If $A_r\cap G\neq\varnothing$ or $B_r\not\subset G$, the guess can be wrong, in which case we can choose $A_{r+1}=A_r$ and $B_{r+1}=B_r\setminus G$ where $\Delta\le|G\cap B|=2$.
If $A_r\cap G=\varnothing$ and $B_r\subset G$, the guess can be one-off, in which case we can choose $A_{r+1}=A_r$ and $B_{r+1}=B_r$ where $\Delta=0$.


$|G\cap A|=3$:

If $A_r\cap G\neq\varnothing$ and $B_r\not\subset G$, the guess can be wrong, in which case we can choose $A_{r+1}=A_r\cap G$ and $B_{r+1}=B_r\setminus G$ where $\Delta\le|A\setminus G|+|G\cap B|=2$.
If $A_r\cap G=\varnothing$ and $B_r\not\subset G$, the guess can be one-off, in which case we can choose $A_{r+1}=A_r$ and $B_{r+1}=B_r\setminus G$ where $\Delta\le|G\cap B|=1$.
If $A_r\cap G\neq\varnothing$ and $B_r\subset G$, the guess can be one-off, in which case we can choose $A_{r+1}=A_r\cap G$ and $B_{r+1}=B_r$ where $\Delta\le|A\setminus G|=1$.
If $A_r\cap G=\varnothing$ and $B_r\subset G$, the guess can be correct, in which case we can choose $A_{r+1}=A_r$ and $B_{r+1}=B_r$ where $\Delta=0$.


$|G\cap A|=4$: The guess is one-off, so we can choose $A_{r+1}=A_r$ and $B_{r+1}=B_r$ where $\Delta=0$.

For all $G$, we can choose $A_{r+1}$ and $B_{r+1}$ so that $\Delta\le2$. Because $|A_0|+|B_0|=16$, by induction, we can choose $A_6$ and $B_6$ so that $|A_6|+|B_6|\ge16-2\cdot6=4$.

If $|A_6\times B_6|\ge4$, for every seventh guess, one of the three possible outcomes will leave at least two remaining connections.
If $|A_6\times B_6|\le3$, then either $|A_6|=1$ and $|B_6|=3$ or $|A_6|=3$ and $|B_6|=1$. Every two distinct pairs in $A_6\times B_6$ correspond to two connections that differ in only word, so every guess has only two possible outcomes (one-off and correct/wrong) among them, one of which will leave at least two remaining connections.

In either case, multiple connections are possible after seven guesses, so eight guesses are insufficient.

I don't understand all the details yet but you have my upvote regardless.  I did not think a non-computer proof was possible.

I read the proof now and I think it all works.  I was initially worried about always keeping it so all pairs in $A_r \times B_r$ are possible, since it seems like the opponent could get useful partial information.  However, I didn't see any issues with this, as each time you are generous with which elements of $A_r$ and $B_r$ are eliminated.  I wish I could upvote a second time =).
